# Spring JDBC Template Map result of multiple queries to One Domain Object

Tags: java, spring, join, jdbctemplate

I am new to Java Spring.

I have 2 tables from where i need to get customer information. I CANNOT JOIN the tables as size of tables is HUGE.
One table contains ID, Name and Phone while other contains ID and Address.
Please note that one customer can have multiple addresses.

I am executing 2 queries via JDBCTemplate. One to get records from first table and other to get records from 2nd table.

how do i join the output to queries to one domain object Customer and send response. What options i have if i dont want to use JOIN in my SQL query and want to execute the 2 queries separately?

Thanks

Tried storing output of first query into a Map and then want to join in with output of 2nd query but not sure if it is the right approach?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: as long as you're using appropriate indices on the tables, a join should not be problematic, even with "huge" tables. The join operation would only acquire the rows which match for the `ON`- or `WHERE`-conditions.
If this still is problematic, you could expand your question to further improve our understanding of what you're trying to achieve.